# Angular - setting the checkbox checked doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I am having a problem on setting the checked property of checkbox. They are checked by default, and when I click it to unchecked for the first time, it turns back to CHECKED but on 2nd, 3rd and so on it works perfectly. By the way it is a formArray.

myhtml.component.html

```
<mat-checkbox [id]="'chkInclude_' + i"
       (click)="setIncludeValue(i,$event)"
       [checked]="test.value.include==1">
</mat-checkbox>
```

myts.component.ts

```
setIncludeValue(index,event){
    if (this.readonly[index]!='true' && this.readonly[index]!='false') this.readonly[index]='false'; //1st uncheck

    if(this.readonly[index]=='false'){
        this.readonly[index]='true';
        this.formArray.at(index).patchValue({include: 0});
    {
    else{
        this.readonly[index]='false';
        this.formArray.at(index).patchValue({include: 1});
    }
}
```

Setting of "include" to 0/1 works perfectly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz, you are not implementing form in angular way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ***(change)*** event on the ***mat-checkbox*** component that fires an event with the state of the check (true/false).

Template:

```
 <mat-checkbox
       (change)="doSomething,$event)"
       [checked]="variable">
</mat-checkbox>
```

Component:

```
doSomething(event) {
 if (event.checked) { //doYourthing}
 else { //doSomethingElse}
 }
```